# Does Lightswitch HTML support full-fledged web application development?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

When LightSwitch first came out I was very intrigued by it, but after an initial evaluation, I learned that you couldn't build a complete browser-based business application with it using standards like HTML5, jQuery, CSS. It only supported Desktop apps with Silverlight and then when the HTML Client came out, that only allowed you to build mobile apps.

But now, I'd like to know if it has matured enough to the point where we can build a complete business-centric, standards-based web app with it? That is, one that runs in a web browser for users to run using a standard web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LightSwitch 2013 HTML outputs html compatible with **IE9+**, Chrome and Firefox, and, as you're already aware, no longer requires Silverlight.  It ships with jQuery 1.9 and is compatible with knockout, amsvis, lodash, winjs to name a few.

To answer your question, yes, it is more than capable to build a complete business-centric web app.  However, being a SPA (Single Page Application) there is a lot of overhead and the initial page load may be unacceptable to many users.  This is ideal for internal networks requiring browser based software to overcome system security policy issues.

For public internet facing web applications i still prefer ASP.NET MVC 5, for many reasons such as bandwidth efficiency, speed, compatibility and flexibility.